# A Massive and Torrid Affair

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, wordplay

> *Is my first part a bargain?  Be careful!  Not quite.
>
>   My next, when it's scarlet, means something's not right.
>
>   My third: to police, an invaluable tool
>
>   Can my last bit be neutral?  It can't, as a rule.*
>
> *If you gather my pieces together, you'll get
>
>   A massive and torrid affair, you can bet.*

Comment: Is the solution a single word, or a phrase?

Comment: The last two lines refer to one word. The lines before that are the parts of that word.

Comment: Elegant, well-written riddle!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution is:

> [**Conflagration**](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20conflagration)
>  Since "*an extensive fire which destroys a great deal of land or property*" could be described as a massive (extensive) and torrid (hot) affair (event).

---

The breakdown in the first four lines is as follows:

*Is my first part a bargain? Be careful! Not quite.*

> **Con** - Initially seems like a bargain, but is actually not (be careful).

*My next, when it's scarlet, means something's not right.*

> **Flag** - A "red flag" is an idiom indicating a warning sign.

*My third: to police, an invaluable tool*

> **Rat** - An informal term used to describe a criminal who gives information to the police

*Can my last bit be neutral? It can't, as a rule.*

> **Ion** - a charged particle (by definition not neutral)

Comment: wow. I've never heard that word. and... How did you figure that out!? nice job.

Comment: @JLee - had a hunch the "torrid affair" was metaphoric, so was looking for words that were big/hot events. Then started with *ion*, as it fit well & is a common suffix. Using that as a starting place I went through lists of [generated words](http://www.litscape.com/word_tools/pattern_match.php) based on reasonable guesses for the other parts (eg. *deal*, *pact* for the first, *x*, *mark*, etc for the second, *cuff*, *gun*, etc for the third). When I tried the pattern *\*flag\*ion* and got conflagration, I had a vague recollection it had to do with fire (and saw that *con* and *rat* fit well).

Comment: @JLee you probably don't play enough RPG's as a Fire Mage. :-)