# Mrs. Malaprop Reads A Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I, Mrs. Malaprop, will recite an original riddle, perspired by [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17878/a-massive-and-torrid-affair) puzzle. Each of lines 1-5 inscribe a part of a word, put them together in sequins to get the one-word answer to the riddle.

First Part: According to the psychiatrist, this is it I suppose.
Second Part: A token creation, the forest is my home.
Third Part: My mood is subjective, though it sometimes depends.
Fourth Part: In the list of apostles, I am one off from the tenth.
Fifth Part: An onion? No, I'm the polar opposite.
Sixth Part: Put us together and what do you get?

For those who love challenge, use what you now know.
If you want more direction, please see below.

> This is similar to the word riddle linked above, with the exception that it is being read by the fictional Mrs. Malaprop for whom the word malapropism is named. As a result, each line of the riddle contains a malapropism. Correct the false words and solve the riddle. A correct answer should contain the words that she meant to use in each line in addition to the final word obtained.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*First Part: According to the psychiatrist, this is it I suppose.*

> Malapropism: "it" -> "id". Solution: **id**.

*Second Part: A token creation, the forest is my home.*

> Malapropism: "token" -> "Tolkien". Solution: **Ent**.

*Third Part: My mood is subjective, though it sometimes depends.*

> Malapropism: "subjective" -> "subjunctive". Solution: **if**. (thanks @dennisdeems)

*Fourth Part: In the list of apostles, I am one off from the tenth.*

> Malapropism: "apostles" -> "epistles" -> "letters". Solution: **I**. (thanks @GentlePurpleRain and @BaileyM)

*Fifth Part: An onion? No, I'm the polar opposite.*

> Malapropism: "onion" -> "anion". Solution: **cation**. (thanks @CodeNewbie)

*Sixth Part: Put us together and what do you get?*

> IDENTIFICATION

Comment: token -> Tolkien.  The Ent is a Tolkien creation who lives in the forest.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Yep, I had the same idea and edited it in while you were commenting!

Comment: I thought I put too many layers, looks like I didn't make it hard enough! Your final result is correct; I'll wait for you to finish the malapropisms before I comment on them

Comment: subjective -> subjunctive

Comment: Union is a malapropism for anion. Polar opposite is cation.

Comment: So apostles must be a malapropism for "letters of the alphabet" in some form (I is one off from the 10th letter).

Comment: Perhaps it's apostle -> epistle?

Comment: So it's ID / ENT / IF / I / CATION.

Comment: @BaileyM:  Well, epistle does mean "letter," but in the sense of a missive, not a character of the alphabet.  Perhaps that's it, though.

Comment: This was a great group effort! Thanks to everyone who commented :-)

Comment: Great job guys! Didn't take as long as I thought. Any feedback on the puzzle style or creation or posing? And would anyone be interested in more of these types?

Comment: @NeedAName I really liked the style of puzzle, and would definitely like to see more of these (as long as they don't flood the site like spaghetti puzzles did back in the day). I thought the best clues were the 2nd and 5th; the 1st was confusing because the malapropism was the same as the solution, the 3rd was a bit weird because "if" doesn't always go together with subjunctive verbs, and the 4th was a bit of a stretch for the reason GentlePurpleRain said.

Comment: @NeedAName also, for the future, you probably needn't tell us the gimmick to your puzzle - I think the hints in the beginning along with the name used were enough to clue us in!

Comment: @randal'thor: Yeah before I added the layer of malapropisms the 4th clue was just a pun of epistle. Also the intended malapropism for the first line was psychiatrist->psychologist, but it ended up being too close to the original meaning.
Bailey: Shortly after creation, someone suggested edits to my post correcting the misspellings in the introduction. I took that as an indication that it was too cryptic and decided to add more info to make it clear what was going on.